# make inner div wider than the outer div

Tags: jquery, html, css, width

I have two divs. The name of the outer div is scroll_main and the inner div is scroll_holder . the width of the outer div is 750px and overflow is set to auto. In the inner div I have added some div with a fixed width and height and float left. so I want to make the width of the inner div auto so that all the contain div of the inner section show in one row. I want to scroll from left to right. Is it possible? thanks

here is the html

```
<div class="scroll_main">
    <div class="scroll_holder">
        <div style="width:400px; height:400px; background:#333; float:left; margin:10px"></div>
        <div style="width:400px; height:400px; background:#999; float:left;margin:10px"></div>
        <div style="width:400px; height:400px; background:#ccc; float:left;margin:10px"></div>
        <div style="width:400px; height:400px; background:#22b1b5; float:left;margin:10px"></div>
        <div style="width:400px; height:400px; background:#333; float:left; margin:10px"></div>
        <div style="width:400px; height:400px; background:#999; float:left;margin:10px"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is the css I have tried to apply

```
.scroll_main {
  height: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 97%;
  overflow: auto;
  position:relative;

  width:750px
}
 .scroll_holder{overflow:hidden; margin:5px; width:750px; overflow:auto }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CSS**

```
.scroll_main {
  height:450px;
  margin:0 auto;
  max-width:97%;
  overflow:auto;
  position:relative;
  width:750px
}
 .scroll_holder{
   margin:5px;
   white-space:nowrap;
 }
.scroll_holder div {
  float:none !important;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

[Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/roughtron/pen/RNPPda)

Comment: I would personally advise *not* using the `!important` tag.

Answer (score 1):

## Option 1

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/u9Xx6/2/) Is what I think you are looking for (although with smaller sizes):

```
#images {
    overflow-y:hidden;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    height:80px;
    width:150px;
    border:solid 1px #c4c4c4;
}
#images2
{

    width:300px;
}

#images img
{
    display:block;
    padding:5px;
    cursor:pointer;
float:left;
}
```

---

## Option 2

[this](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/u9Xx6/3/) demonstrates another technique using this css:

```
div {
    overflow:hidden;

}
#frame {
    width:600px;

    padding:8px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
#thumbnails_container {

    border:1px solid black;
    padding:4px;
    overflow-x:scroll;
        height:200px;
}
.thumbnail {
    border:1px solid black;
    margin-right:4px;
    width:100px; height:75px;
    float:left;
}
.thumbnail img {
    width:100px; height:710px;
}
```

This also allows thumbnails if you were using it for images.

Another Option would be to use the `no-wrap` to stop the divs from wrapping

Comment: yes the problem is if I increase the items then it is not showing

Answer (score -1):

Research about style properties ***overflow-y*** and ***overflow-x***, try to avoid having a DIV with a fixed width or height  positioned absolutely within a DIV with a auto or variable width or height without a minimum height or with defined, both DIVS will not show up in some browsers (internet explorer) :)

Comment: it may help a user who has had his answer voted down to understand how to answer questions in a more helpful way if the user who voted down the answer adds a comment why he or she did so...